# Escaping single quote in a sed command containing variables containing color escape codes?

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I'm using `sed` to replace every instance of `" is "` by a colorized `"'s "`.

To do this, it surrounds the result by a color variable **r** and a blank variable **x**, which are interpreted literally. `echo -e` then makes the colors appear. Nothing new here.

The problem arises when I try to add the apostrophe (which is actually a single quote); I can't escape it without messing up the color escape code.

Here is my code without the apostrophe I'm trying to add:

```
r='\e[0;31m'                    # red
x='\e[0m'                       # reset color
sed 's/ is /\'${r}'s\'${x}'/g'  # replace " is " by "'s "
```

I tried double quotes, multiple backslashes, but everything either broke the color code, or failed to escape the single quote. In the meantime, I'm using a true apostrophe ( **’** ), but it it's not the best solution, because it doesn't render properly in the TTY.

Comment: for portability (ahem... well, if the machines and terminals you port it to use the same Ansi codes for colors...):  `r="$(printf '\033[0;31m')" ; x="$(printf '\033[0;31m')"` (I know you could drop the " here, but I like them for a more general use, in case you add spaces or tabs or returns somewhere...)

Comment: You mean `x="$(printf '\033[0m')"`

Comment: oops, indeed ^^ I stupidly did a copy/paste of my r variable... thx for pointing it out: `r="$(printf '\033[0;31m')" ; x="$(printf '\033[0m')"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep the single quotes, then you need `'"'"'`

The first quote ends the current single quoted string. Then we have `"'"` which expands to a single quote. `\'` would also work but doesn't look as good.

The last single quote starts the quoted string again.

An alternative in your case would be `"s/ is /${r}'s${x}/g"` (i.e. only use double quotes).

But then, you need to use `r='\\e[0;31m'` because the expansion in the string will string one level of escapes.

Comment: Your suggestion yields: `e[0;31m'se[0m` (the variables' backslash is missing), and adding it directly to `sed` like so: `sed "s/ is /\\${r}'s\\${x}/g"` yields the expected output, except that `echo -e` fails to interpret the color codes and sees them as strings instead.

Comment: Use `r='\\e[0;31m'` for the double quoted version at the end.

Comment: Still, echo just prints it verbatim. This works, but it's very ugly:      **echo -e \`echo -e " is " | sed "s/ is /${r}'s${x}/g"\`**

Comment: How about `r=$(echo -e "\e[0;31m")`? Then no `-e` for the final echo.

Comment: And did you try my initial suggestion? That should really work.

Comment: It works if `r="$(printf '\033[0;31m')"` or `r=$(echo -e "\e[0;31m")`, as you and Olivier Dulac suggested, but not if `r='\e[0;31m'`, as I initially tried.

Comment: I meant: Did you try `'"'"'`?

Comment: It makes no difference. `echo -e " is " | sed 's/ is /\'${r}''"'"'s\'${x}'/g'` works with your variable definitions, but not with mine.

Comment: Run that with `set -x` to see what the shell finally processes. I'm pretty sure there are problems with the single quotes.

Comment: You were right. After getting some sleep, `'"'"'` works perfectly.